# SQL syntax error around 'uniqueidentifier'

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting this error in SQL Server

> Code:156, Message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'rule'.

for

```
CREATE TABLE Control  
(
    id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    rule nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

I'm not sure what causes the problem.

Comment: and you need to quote the column name

Comment: @isaace it's an integer. Should it be included?

Comment: `RULE` is a keyword. Put it in square brackets.

Comment: What database system are you using? (E.g. [tag:mysql], [tag:oracle], [tag:sql-server], etc) I don't recognise that particular form of error message (it looks similar to a MySQL one but with some parts chopped out/rearranged). `uniqueidentifier` is only, so far as I'm aware, a data type in [tag:sql-server] (possible SyBase too)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it is sql-server

Comment: A SQL Server error message for syntax errors would be something very close to `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.` (just with variation of what's in the quotes at the end). Either you're working with some intermediate product that is "translating" the error message or it's not SQL Server.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the error above is given by [this](https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/) syntax validator. On java spring/hibernate backend I'm getting: Error Code:156, Message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'rule'.

Comment: Again, put square brackets around `RULE`. It is a keyword, and must be referenced with square brackets if you wish to use it.

Comment: @neptune That syntax validator does not use SQL Server parsing rules and rejects valid SQL Server queries. In this case the reasons for SQL Server's error message and for EverSQL's error message are the same, but don't put too much faith in that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments put `rule` in brackets. It's a keyword in SQL Server.

```
CREATE TABLE Control (
  id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
  [rule] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Or alternatively use a *more descriptive*, more intuitive name **other** than just `Rule` ....